# Unexpected IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, debugging, runtime-error, iteration, indexoutofboundsexception

Lately I have been complete befuddled by a strange bug in my code and got to the point of extreme frustration. Eventually I went and put in `System.out.println();`'s in my code until I narrowed it down, to reveal the most bizarre of results.  Here is the code:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  i = it.next();
  System.out.println(DeathWish.getInstanceListReference()
                     .get(DeathWish.getInstanceListReference().size() -1) );
  System.out.println("Golden number: " + 
                     (DeathWish.getInstanceListReference().size() -1) );
  System.out.println((DeathWish.getInstanceListReference().size() -1) == i);
  System.out.println("CurrentInstance List: " + 
                     Arrays.toString(DeathWish.getInstanceListReference().toArray()));
  System.out.println("Iteration: " + i);
  try {
    System.out.println( DeathWish.getInstanceListReference()
      .remove((int)list.get(i))); //remove unwanted objects from game paint list
  } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex + " Error with multiple GameObj objects");
  } finally {
    System.out.println("\n");
  }
}
```

and the output:

```
DeathWish.Bullet@ddd5de
Golden number: 2
true
CurrentInstance List: [DeathWish.Player@3a5cf7, DeathWish.Bullet@6cca54, DeathWish.Bullet@ddd5de]
Iteration: 2
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2 Error with multiple GameObj objects
```

`getInstanceListReference()` returns an `ArrayList<GameObj>`. `GameObj` is one of the super-super classes in my project that represents Game Objects. Additionally, the `ArrayList` that `getInstanceListReference()` returns is not being modified by internal source code during runtime.

There is some code that is executed before the for loop:

```
System.out.println("\n------------------------\n" + "Read Instance List: " + Arrays.toString(tmpLock.toArray()) + "|" + Arrays.toString(tmpLock1.toArray()));
System.out.println("Recycle Bin: " + recycleBin.get(0) + "|" + recycleBin.get(1) + "\n------------------------\n");
```

This *list* in the source code in the very top refers to the `recycleBin`. It holds the indices of objects that are scheduled to be removed. The for loop with the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is looping through the integers in `recycleBin` and utilizing them to remove indices in the instance list.

Am I doing some bad practice I'm not aware of that is causing the issue?

Comment: Post [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't accessing that list from another thread?  Try adding synchronized() around all accesses to the listReference, where it is written and read.  This smells strongly of thread problems.

Comment: Yes I am sure that I am not accessing from another thread. For good measure I added the synchronized modifier to my get Methods. I could not add the synchronized modifier to the ArrayList reference itself because I am using encapsulation (for noobs: the reference has a private modifier and a get method to pass the value on to other classes).

Comment: You all but certainly have not "discovered a bug with Java" and that should not be the first explanation you jump to.  It is *far* more likely you have discovered a bug in *your code*.  If you post an SSCCE as suggested, we can help you debug and understand it.

Comment: 'I have discovered a bug in Java' is always the last issue I think of. It's the output and the source code in this example that is leading me to believe that this is a bug. I will take a look at the SSCCE you suggested.

Comment: I read the SSCCE and I believe I have all the components correct except 'Self Contained' I can post my entire project if that would help?

Comment: No, that would violate the "Short" requirement. The idea is to share something people can look at and run easily.  Often times, simply trying to simplify your problem down to an SSCCE will help you uncover the issue yourself.

Comment: I don't think I can make this question more SSCCE then. Perhaps I don't fully understand SSCCE?

Comment: There's not much to understand.... we're asking you to post code we can run, as the code snippets you've provided are not enough to debug your problem.

Comment: The for loop is contained in an anonymous interclass, inside a larger class that extends Jpanel with 348 lines of code. You would also need to have my main class that has 200+ lines of code. Also required would be the many child classes of GameObj. I am unable to post code you could run because it would be enormous, which Is why I was offering to link my project earlier.

Comment: You're missing the point - the rest of your code (presumably) isn't the cause of the problem.  Attempt to replicate the issue with the theoretically irrelevant code removed.  For instance, like sscce.org suggests, remove any graphical interface if that's not part of the issue.  Here, I would think you could strip out the anonymous class and just iterate over, say, a list of integers.  If your code is so complex and interconnected that extracting smaller components is not possible, then that is your bad practice; structure your code into separate parts that can be tested individually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59909/discussion-between-dimo414-and-kiro-yakuza).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without an SSCCE that we can *run* ourselves, we cannot give you an answer for certain.  However based on the description and comments you've posted, here is one possible explanation that comes to mind:

---

You are concurrently modifying a list you are iterating over, in a way that fails to trigger a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).  Despite the name, it is perfectly possible to run into this sort of issue even in a single thread; here's a simple example (an SSCCE, if you will):

```
int len = ls.size();
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if(i %2 == 0) {
    ls.remove(i);
  }
}
```

As this modifies the list while iterating over it, `i` becomes disconnected from the elements of the list.  Instead of removing the even elements, as might be the intended behavior, this will remove the 0th, 3rd, 6th, and so on, until it `IndexOutOfBoundException`s partway through the loop.

Generally, the correct way to avoid this issue is to iterate over one collection, and modify a copy, or to *only* work with the `Iterator` for the duration of your removal operations.  For instance, this is a safe way to remove every other element - notice that instead of working with indicies, we work solely with the iterator, which internally holds its position in the list regardless of what is removed:

```
Iterator<?> iter = ls.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
  iter.next();
  iter.remove();
  if(iter.hasNext()) {
    iter.next();
  }
}
```

---

Ok, lets try another example, based more directly on the code in your loop.

I have a list of indicies I'd like to remove from another list:

```
List<Integer> toRemove = Arrays.asList(0,2,4,6);
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(
                        Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"));
```

Now, if I try to remove idexes 0, 2, 4, and 6 from `myList`, I will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because as I call `.remove()` the list shrinks by one, and all elements later in the list move down one.

```
for(int i : toRemove) {
  myList.remove(i);
}
```

While I can't say exactly what is right for your use case, one option is to leave the original list intact, modify a copy, then store that modified copy once all changes have been made.  Here's one way to do that:

```
Set<Integer> toRemoveSet = new HashSet<>(toRemove);
List<String> cleanList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
  if(!toRemoveSet.contains(i)) {
    cleanList.add(myList.get(i));
  }
}
System.out.println(cleanList);
```

Instead of removing items one by one, we check to see if each index should be kept or not, and skip any that shouldn't.  This avoids the inconsistent state of trying to remove items from a list that's shrinking as you work on it.

---

In general, mutable collections can be tricky to work with as projects grow in size.  The excellent Guava library provides a set of [immutable collections](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) specifically to help people avoid these sorts of issues.  It requires a slightly different way of thinking about solving problems, but it's a much more robust way.  Even if you don't use Guava, consider your collections immutable whenever possible, and make defensive copies when attempting structural modifications.

Comment: also your example differs from my 'inconsistency'
in that I had the list aka. recycleBin
load the largest indices first so that when the removal process happened it wouldn't affect the data behind it. The instanceList I refer to in my example
is the DeathWish.getInstanceListReference()
which returns an ArrayList of GameObj

Comment: I'm going to try your iter.remove() technique

Comment: Note you can't use indices with `iter.remove()` - you should have no calls to `get(i)` or anything similar inside of the iterator loop.

Comment: If I am correct doesn't immutable refer to unchanging over time or unable to be changed? Do you mean immutable collection as in the reference cannot change (final) or the items themselves in the list cannot be removed, added, or rearranged?

Comment: An immutable collection cannot be restructured or resized - the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList()` is one example of such a collection.  There are many benefits to using collections that are explicitly immutable, but also simply to treating collections as if they were immutable, even when they might not be.

Answer (score 1):

I would re-write `accept()` to use Java library methods that are available to you for working with collections.

- You method `accept()` is passed a `Collection<Integer>` that represents indices that you want to remove from `DeathWith.getInstanceListReference()`.
- You're currently dealing with modifying a collection while iterating on it.

Consider using `Collections.removeAll()` to accomplish what (I believe) you need.

```
public void accept(Set<Integer> deadIndices) {
    for (int i : deadIndices) {
        DeathWish.getInstanceListReference().set(i, null);
    }
    List<GameObj> nullList = new ArrayList<GameObj>();
    nullList.add(null);
    DeathWish.getInstanceListReference().removeAll(nullList);
}
```

This assumes:

- `null` is an invalid value in `DeathWish.getInstanceListReference()`.

Comment: Slightly safer, but using `null` or any sentinel value similarly has the potential to break-down - if the list already contains `null`, you will run into problems.  Ultimately, using `.removeAll()` as a proxy for removing specific indices is like using a screwdriver as a hammer - it'll work just fine right until you take your eye out with it.

Comment: I thought about this method before: nullifying finished game objects and then checking whether they were null, but I never tried it. Also why would you run into problems if there were already null values? Wouldn't the removeAll simply remove them?

Comment: @KiroYakuza If your program never adds `null` to `DeathWish.getInstanceListReference()` than this is _okay_ (but not an ideal solution)

Comment: @dimo414, yes - however the screwdriver is well designed and a quality tool, while the hammer is a brand you've never tried before - the gotchas are important to note for sure

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is coming from your `list.get(i)` which I assume has only 2 elements and not from the `DeathWish.getInstanceListReference()` list!

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention that the list is actually my 'recycleBin'. It checks objects in the instanceList ArrayList and adds the index of the object that meets a certain condition. Here is more output: Read Instance List: [DeathWish.Player@a8409d, DeathWish.Bullet@1fcd8fd, DeathWish.Bullet@24f455]       
Recycle Bin: [2, 1]|[]. *Yes it was recompiled with my synchronized edits, but I still got the same other output including the error.

Comment: Trying to fetch the 3rd object from your recycle bin is causing the issue. `list.get(i)` on line 291 is what fails because there are only two items in it (2, 1) but you're trying to read the 3rd item. This is not a bug with java, this is a bug with your code.

Comment: There are only two integers representing instanceList indices in the recycle bin: [2,1]. There isn't a 3rd object. The instanceList contains 3 objects: [player@...,bullet@...,bullet@...]. The recycleBin maintains that the bullet's at their respective indices 2 and 1 need to be removed. the player reference is never capable of removing the player instance.

Comment: That is exactly the problem! You are taking the 2 from [2,1] and try to fetch list.get(2) and you have only 2 elements there [2,1]

Comment: So the it.next() is returning the element before the first actual element? But if the for loop initializer of it is the `size()` of list, wouldn't that mean it is intializing `size() + 1`? and the next is getting the next value, essentially `list.size()`?

Comment: the it.next() is returning 2 in the first loop and in the try block you are doing: System.out.println(DeathWish.getInstanceListReference().remove((int)list.get(i))); doing list.get(2) here is when fails

Comment: I suppose that you meant to got for DeathWish.getInstanceListReference().remove(i)